# how to get concatenation of nested List<Long> with java collector

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'd like to retrieve the distinct list of Longs given this nested structure:

```
Class A
public List<B> getBs()

Class B
public List<Long> getIds()


List<A> list = ...
// how do I now get all of longs as a distinct list
```

I realise I can do 2 for loops but given Java8's new abilities which I'm only just getting used to I'm sure there is a better way.

To clarify, I require `List<long>` (not `List<A>`)

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused do you want List<A> or List<Long>?

Comment: clarified in question. I require List<Long>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like the code below should work - you go down the nested structure with `map`, then you "flatMap" the list of ids into one concatenated stream of Longs on which you can apply the `distinct` intermediate operation.

```
List<A> list = ...;
List<Long> uniqueIds = list.stream()                 //Stream<A>
                           .map(A::getBs)            //Stream<List<B>>
                           .flatMap(List::stream)    //Stream<B>
                           .map(B::getIds)           //Stream<List<Long>>
                           .flatMap(List::stream)    //Stream<Long>
                           .distinct()
                           .collect(toList());
```